# Sort XML file structure representation recursively by name - foders first

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, filepath

I am trying to sort a XML representation of a file system structure. 
I have tried using a XSLT to sort, but cannot get it o work completely. 
The XML is generated using PHP FilesystemIterator, and I want to sort recursively by:

1. Folders first in alphabetical ascending order
2. Files last in alphabetical ascending order

Hoever, I cannot quite get it to work as intended.

My original XML:

```
<rows parent="0">
    <row id="1" sortOrder="1" isFolder="true" fileName="BFolder">
        <cell image="folder.gif">BFolder</cell>
        <row id="2" sortOrder="2" fileName="Moved.jpg">
            <cell>Moved.jpg</cell>
        </row>
        <row id="3" sortOrder="2" fileName="MFile.mp4">
            <cell>MFile.mp4</cell>
        </row>
        <row id="4" sortOrder="2" fileName="AFile.jpg">
            <cell>AFile.jpg</cell>
        </row>
        <row id="5" sortOrder="1" isFolder="true" fileName="Movies">
            <cell image="folder.gif">Movies</cell>
            <row id="6" sortOrder="2" fileName="Sfile.mp4">
                <cell>SFile.mp4</cell>
            </row>
            <row id="23" sortOrder="1" isFolder="true" fileName="974">
                <cell image="folder.gif">974</cell>

                <row id="24" sortOrder="2" fileName="Vägguttag.jpeg">
                    <cell>Vägguttag.jpeg</cell>
                </row>
                <row id="25" sortOrder="2" fileName="VU.jpeg">
                    <cell>VU.jpeg</cell>
                </row>
            </row>
        </row>
        <row id="14" sortOrder="2" fileName="004.png">
            <cell>004.png</cell>
        </row>
        <row id="15" sortOrder="2" fileName="003.png">
            <cell>003.png</cell>
        </row>
    </row>
    <row id="10" sortOrder="2" fileName="BB.pdf">
        <cell>BB.pdf</cell>
    </row>
    <row id="16" sortOrder="2" fileName="BA.pdf">
        <cell>BA.pdf</cell>
    </row>
    <row id="17" sortOrder="2" fileName="C.js">
        <cell>C.js</cell>
    </row>
    <row id="1" sortOrder="1" isFolder="true" fileName="AFolder">
        <cell image="folder.gif">Renamed</cell>
    </row>
</rows>
```

I would like it sorted like this:

```
<rows parent="0">
    <row id="1" sortOrder="1" isFolder="true" fileName="AFolder">
        <cell image="folder.gif">Renamed</cell>
    </row>
    <row id="1" sortOrder="1" isFolder="true" fileName="BFolder">
        <cell image="folder.gif">BFolder</cell>
        <row id="5" sortOrder="1" isFolder="true" fileName="Movies">
            <cell image="folder.gif">Movies</cell>
            <row id="23" sortOrder="1" isFolder="true" fileName="974">
                <cell image="folder.gif">974</cell>
                <row id="25" sortOrder="2" fileName="1.jpeg">
                    <cell>1.jpeg</cell>
                </row>
                <row id="24" sortOrder="2" fileName="2.jpeg">
                    <cell>2.jpeg</cell>
                </row>
            </row>
            <row id="6" sortOrder="2" fileName="Sfile.mp4">
                <cell>SFile.mp4</cell>
            </row>
        </row>
        <row id="15" sortOrder="2" fileName="003.png">
            <cell>003.png</cell>
        </row>
        <row id="14" sortOrder="2" fileName="004.png">
            <cell>004.png</cell>
        </row>
        <row id="4" sortOrder="2" fileName="AFile.jpg">
            <cell>AFile.jpg</cell>
        </row>
        <row id="3" sortOrder="2" fileName="MFile.mp4">
            <cell>MFile.mp4</cell>
        </row>
        <row id="2" sortOrder="2" fileName="Moved.jpg">
            <cell>Moved.jpg</cell>
        </row>
    </row>
    <row id="16" sortOrder="2" fileName="BA.pdf">
        <cell>BA.pdf</cell>
    </row>
    <row id="10" sortOrder="2" fileName="BB.pdf">
        <cell>BB.pdf</cell>
    </row>
    <row id="17" sortOrder="2" fileName="C.js">
        <cell>C.js</cell>
    </row>
</rows>
```

The XSLT i have tried:

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
            <xsl:sort select="@sortOrder" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="@fileName" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but your second template only matched the root element.  Change it like this:

```
<xsl:template match="rows|row">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:sort select="@sortOrder" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="@fileName" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed that! Also, thanks for specifying the "match" attribute, it's always good to be specific.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: remove the `/` from

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
```

to get

```
<xsl:template match="*">
```

Otherwise you'd only sort the elements at the root node level.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I somehow missed that!